# VMware console image quality

Tags: vmware, console, esxi, workstation

Is there a way to increase image quality in VMware console - both in the ESXi and Workstation?

I'm using it daily and really don't like the fact that image given from the VM is compressed - just like JPEG. I would like to see it exactly as it is on normal, non-virtualized system. It's gigabit LAN, so the bandwidth and latency aren't an issue.

I'm attaching a screenshot which reflects the situation. Just zoom at it and you will see pixels around menu labels, toolbar icons, window title etc.

*Keep in mind, that this is what I see while working on the console - it is not due the fact of taking screenshot (which is PNG by the way).*

[image]

Comment: What version of ESXi and Workstation are you running?  What version of Windows are you running within the VM? Which web console are you using exactly? On my version of vCenter I am offered two different versions of the console.

Comment: Workstation 16.1.2, ESXi 6.0.0u3. It's the same both on the Workstation, Web console and downloadable console. Windows XP here, but the same happens on Windows Server 2012 R2.